# Most efficient way of converting plain text to HTML, Match or Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, plaintext

I have a large text document filled with random words, urls, email-addresses etc. An example: "word 2014 john@doe.com http://www.example.com/ http://example.com/image.gif", but it could look differently, there could be linebreaks, multiple spaces, tabs etc. And the data could very fast become huge (it is a type of bookmarking service so data is arriving all the time in the form of images, text and hyperlinks).

Another example of content in the text document (the one I use for testing):

```
http://movpod.in/images3/MovPod-logo.png
https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/developers/chooser-drawing-vfln1ftk6.png
http://xregexp.com/assets/regex_cookbook.gif
asd asd ad feaf
apa
http
```

I want to wrap all these strings in tags, and be able to target out images, hyperlinks, emails and strings. I have tried different ways but unsure which is the best, and also, there is a RegExp I do not fully understand.

The end result should be:

```
<span>word</span>
<span>2014</span> 
<a class="mail" href="mailto:john@doe">john@doe.com</a> 
<a class="url" href="http://www.example.com/">http://www.google.com/</a> 
<a class="img" href="http://example.com/image.gif">http://example.com/image.gif</a>"
```

**Match**. This approach is however not keeping the text order intact, but it works.

```
arr = data.split("\n");
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    arr2 = arr[i].split(' ');
    for (j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++)
    {
        if (arr2[j].match(/(.gif|.png|.jpg|.jpeg)/))
        {
            ext = arr2[j].substr(-4);
            ext = ext.replace(".","");
            imgs += '<a class="img '+ext+'" href="'+arr2[j]+'">'+arr2[j]+'</a>';
        }
        else if (arr2[j].match(/(http:)/))
        {
            urls += '<a class="url" href="'+arr2[j]+'">'+arr2[j]+'</a>';
        }
        else
        {
            spans += '<span>'+arr2[j]+'</span>';
        }
    }
}
```

**Regexp**. I thought it would be possible to look for the inverse at exp_all, as in anything else but containing http. It does not however.

```
var exp_img     = /(https?:\/\/([\S]+?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))/g,
    exp_link    = /([^"])(https?:\/\/([a-z-\.]+)+([a-z]{2,4})([\/\w-_]+)\/?)/g,
    exp_all     = /^((?!http).)*$/g;

    text        = data.replace(exp_all, '<span>$3</span>');
    text        = text.replace(exp_img, '<a class="img" href="$1">$1</a>');
    text        = text.replace(exp_link, '<a class="url" href="$2">$2</a>');
```

So, the best way of accomplishing this plain-text to HTML conversion would be appreciated. I would love if there was already some type of library for this. I was looking at Markdown but then I would still have to update the plain-text for the Markdown, so I guess not an option.

And if possible I would like to strip out "http://" and have it as clean and neat as possible.

Comment: Don't use javascript php is more powerful and it'll do just what you want. If this is the direction you want please ask your question to this format. I know sometimes we are limited but if you have access to a server of sorts then this will be possible with php

Comment: I am fetching the text-content through javascript and would like it to remain in that sphere. basically i have a chrome extension that saves a .txt to a dropbox folder. that .txt contains a lot of random content, could be anything in the world of text. I then want to decipher it and turn it into html so i can separate images from other urls, and also turn words into spans. if possible i would like to not involve php.

Comment: Best way to generate an html file from a txt file would be going through it and derrière each word after checking with regex then we can dynamically create html in pushing the word wrapped in the corresponding tags

Comment: yes, in my code i imagine this is what i am doing for hyperlinks and images, but to capture the rest in spans, i do not know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also let the RegEx engine tell you what a block of text is based on what Group it puts it in,

i.e. image, other url, email, or text.

```
const generateHTML = s => {
  const pattern = /(https?:\/\/\S*(?:\.gif|\.png]+))|(https?:\/\/\S*)|([a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,})|(\S*)/gi
  return s.replace(pattern, (_, g1, g2, g3, g4) =>
    g1 ? `<a class="img" href="${g1}">${g1}</a><br/>` :
      g2 ? `<a class="url" href="${g2}">${g2}</a><br/>` :
        g3 ? `<a class="mail" href="mailto:${g3}">${g3}</a><br/>` :
          g4 ? `<span>${g4}</span><br/>` : ``);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Im making a few assumptions about your data (for example, that every entry is always there.) If that's true, then something like this should work fine:

```
    <script>

    var data = ['word\n 2014\t\t    john@doe.com\n\n\n\n\n http://www.example.com/ http://example.com/image.gif apa http',
                'fooo 2013 foo@bar.com http://www.blah.com/ http://blah.com/gif.gif asd asd ad feaf'];

    function htmlify(string){
        var elem = string.replace(/[^\w\s\/@:\.]/g,'').replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ');
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
            if (elem[i].match(/http:/)) {
                if (elem[i].substr(-4).match(/.gif|.png|.jpg|.jpeg/)){
                    result.push("<a class='img' href='" + elem[i] + "'>" + elem[i] + "</a>");
                } else {
                    result.push( "<a class='url' href='" + elem[i] + "'>" + elem[i] + "</a>");
                }
            } else if (elem[i].match(/\w+@\w+\.\w+/)){
                    result.push("<a class='mail' href='mailto:" + elem[i] + "'>" + elem[i] + "</a>");
            } else {
                result.push("<span>" + elem[i] + "</span>");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    var result = data.map(htmlify);
    console.log(result);

    </script>
```

Comment: The data is dynamic, information will be added and there could be linebreaks as well. I will update my post.

Comment: string.replace(/\n/g,'').split(' ') as added will deal with line breaks. The bigger issue is assuming that each element exists and ' ' is the correct delimiter.

Comment: still, my content does not always look like in the example, its a mix of everything, and new data is randomly added. so there is no order. the only constant is that there will be strings and i need to wrap tags around images, links, emails and all other text nodes. it should be possible to remove all spaces as well no and just leave one?

Comment: If you don't know the order, then you'd have to check everything. Edited, though I doubt this ends up being the most efficient method. ;)

Comment: yes your solution is similar to the one i already have, albeit more elegant.